# Version my website deploying into azure app service via kudu (asp.net mvc)

Tags: azure, teamcity, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have a website built on asp.net mvc that is deployed into azure app service using deployment scripts (powered by kudu). I would like to have each version deployed incremented with a central build number like 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.2 etc.

I could easily achieve this with teamcity with the build number concept that is part of the teamcity scripts. And, as a deployment step, I could update the AssemblyInfo.cs file with a common file and start the build process.

Has anyone done something similar in kudu scripts.

And, after that i would like to tag my bitbucket with this build number.